# Difference Between requests.get() and read_json

Tags: json, python-requests

I'm having troubling understanding the difference between using requests.get() and read_json() when reading files off the internet. When is it appropriate to use each and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: are you reffering to this [`read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the `read_json()` function in pandas, then calling the function on a json string or file converts the string or file into a pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) (an object specific to the pandas library). `requests.get('https://blahblah.com')` returns a [Response](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object, specific to the requests library.

You can read up on the attributes and methods associated with each object at the attached links. Hope this helps!